# JS library to access or clone a github repo

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, github, express

Is there a way to access a github repo from my node.js server?

The server should be able to access the source files located in the git repo, either by creating a temporary folder and cloning the repo, or be accessing the directly.

Comment: at the end of the day, git are only files. so yeah, it should be possible, the same as fetching any other file from an server.

Comment: You should try https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github. It's an API wrapper, allows you to do what you want + many more :)

Comment: On every GH page there's a link to http://developer.github.com/ titled "API". Read it.

Comment: Try @gustavohenke's idea. Also, always keep in mind that in a worst case scenario, Node can do anything that works in the commandline because it can pass commands to the commandline via `child_process.exec`. Check it out [here](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be willing to take a peek at the **[js-git](https://github.com/creationix/js-git)** library, which allows one to clone, browse and interact with a git repository.

This project has been launched through two crowd fundraising session (one at **[KickStarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/creationix/js-git)**, the second one at **[BountySource](https://www.bountysource.com/fundraisers/325-js-git)**) and backed by companies like Mozilla or Adobe.

The author also took care of creating a wrapper for js-git that implement all the abstract interfaces using node.js native APIs (see **[git-node](https://github.com/creationix/git-node)**).